# How to select only one MUI ToggleButton within a ToggleButtonGroup when mapping through an array with an unknown length

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, togglebutton

I am using MUI and React to display fixtures (home, draw, away) as a ToggleButton that can be selected. I'd like to have only **one** selection per row. The fixtures change each week, including the number of fixtures.

Per default ToggleButtonGroup allows one selection for **all** fixtures.

I changed the `exclusive` prop to `false` which takes an array but then the user can select multiple result per row, which isn't what I'm trying to achieve.

How can I add logic for only one item per row to be selectable?

**Note**: The fixtures are returned from a database call. I added in the `fixtures` array as an example of what is returned from the database call.

[image: How the fixtures appear with ToggleButtons]

```
const [fixtures, SetFixtures] = useState([{
    gameweek: "loading...", game: "loading...", home: "loading...",
    away: "loading...", draw: "loading...", kickoff_datetime: "loading...", result: "loading...",
  }]);
const [alignment, setAlignment] = useState([]);


const handleChange = (newAlignment) => {
    setAlignment(newAlignment);
  };


const fixtures = [
      { game: "LeicesterArsenal", gameweek: 2, home: "Leicester", away: "Arsenal", draw:"LeicesterArsenalDraw", kickoff_datetime: "2022-07-15T15:30:00", result: null }, 
      { game: "ManchesterUnitedNottinghamForest", game: 2, home: "Manchester United", away: "Nottingham Forest", draw:"ManchesterUnitedNottinghamForestDraw", kickoff_datetime: "2022-07-15T15:30:00", result: null }, 
      { game: "TottenhamWestHam", game: 2, home: "Tottenham", away: "West Ham", draw:"TottenhamWestHamDraw", kickoff_datetime: "2022-07-15T15:30:00", result: null }, 
      { game: "WolvesCrystalPalace", game: 2, home: "Wolves", away: "Crystal Palace", draw:"WolvesCrystalPalaceDraw", kickoff_datetime: "2022-07-15T15:30:00", result: null }]


function RenderFixtures() {
    return fixtures.map((fixture, index) =>
      <div id={"fixture-row-" + index} key={fixture.game}>
      <ToggleButtonGroup
        color="success"
        value={alignment}
        exclusive={true}
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        <ToggleButton value={fixture.home}>{fixture.home}</ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton value={fixture.draw}>Draw</ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton value={fixture.away}>{fixture.away}</ToggleButton>
        </ToggleButtonGroup>
      </div>
```